# Writing Custom HtmlHelpers for MVC3 and MVC4 Beta, should I use HtmlString or MvcHtmlString?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I'm writing some custom Html Helpers for my MVC3 and soon MVC4 project. Examples on the net usually show that it's done with MvcHtmlString, however, I read that if we are using .NET 4, we should be using HtmlString.

What should I use and why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use the highest possible interface/class in the hierarchy when designing something. In this case it's [IHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring.aspx) and you could use it in ASP.NET MVC 3 and 4.

```
public IHtmlString Foo(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    return new HtmlString("foo bar");
}
```

Be careful when returning an `IHtmlString` instance from your helper. This means that it is up to you to properly HTML encode it: